# Array Losing Initialization on Awake

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, initialization

I am initializing two different boolean arrays in my SaveData class. When the Awake function is called, only one of them is remaining initialized. By this, I mean it retains its length of 17 while the other loses its length of 11 and is suddenly a length of 0. The only difference beyond the length is that the one that works is deriving its length from a local enumeration while the other is deriving its length from another classes enumeration. I can put a breakpoint on the initializing line and it will prove that it first initializes to a length of 11 (i.e. the enumerated value is good). Yet when I get to the Awake function, it's magically back to 0 while the other array is still 17. What gives?

Update: 
There must be a bug in Unity. I simply added a letter to the end of the working array which is not used by anyone as evidenced by the lack of errors from the name change, and suddenly it, too, is now being reduced to a size of 0. So... now what?

Simplified Code:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveData : MonoBehaviour {
    public static SaveData saveData;

    public bool[] dumbArray = new bool[(int)ExternalClass.ExternalEnum.LengthViaLastElement]; // 11
    public bool[] goodArray = new bool[(int)LocalEnum.LengthViaLastElement]; // 17

    ...

    public void Awake()
    {
        foreach (bool i in goodArray) Debug.Log(i); // prints 0 to 16
        foreach (bool i in dumbArray) Debug.Log(i); // prints nothing
        if (saveData == null) saveData = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a persistent behavior or randomly occurs? If persistent problem I suspect array assignment could be going wrong somewhere in your code. Post the code where you are touching dumbArray & goodArray before calling Awake(...) function.

Comment: That's what's weird, I'm not touching them before calling awake. But it is a persistent problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! The problem comes into play with the Inspector. My script was attached to an object which, it seems, doesn't care about initialization size except on the first time you attach the code to the object. So the array that didn't work was a new array that I added after attaching the script, and the array that did work was already in the code when I attached the script to the object. The object instance will take default values of new variables but apparently not default array sizes of new arrays. That is awful...

Solution: Initialize arrays in Awake/Start. Of course, this means the inspector will not have control over them which may be bad in some instances.